# Best way to handle web calls using closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures, block

Check the below sample code

```
@IBAction func turnOnLightTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    turnOnLight { (turnON, error) -> Void in
        if turnON {
            // Turn on task - activity performed for 8 seconds
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func turnOffLightTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    turnOffLight { (turnOFF, error) -> Void in
        if turnOFF {
            // Turn off task - activity performed for 1 second
        }
    }
}

func turnOnLight(completion: (turnON: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    // Web call - 3 seconds
    completion(turnON: true, error: nil)
}

func turnOffLight(completion: (turnOFF: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    // Web call - 3 seconds
    completion(turnOFF: true, error: nil)
}
```

I have two `UIButton`s is a same `UIViewController` - One to turn on light and another to turn off light. Each action takes its own time to get response and its own time to perform the `UIactivity` (commented).

Say, I tap TurnON `button` . I would take 3 seconds to get the response from service and the data is handed over to the completion block. The completion block would perform a task for 8 seconds.

Say, after getting the response i.e. when completion closure of TurnON is executing, I tap on TurnOFF button. Totally, in 4 seconds, TurnOFF activity will be done. But, the TurnON activity isn't cancelled and in few seconds, light will be turned on which shouldn't happen.

What is the best way to handle it? There are some hacks I could do, `disable` `userInteraction`, flags, etc. But what is the professional way? Is there a way to cancel the closure task?

My concern is to cancel/stop the closure `activity`, and when another `activity` is started.

Comment: I think that in order to solve your problem you should see if there are any network call in progress, more specifically any call of the inverse type, and send the cancel command to it. Then you will receive an error in completion, that you need to deal (I would say ignore it), with the code -999 wich is NSURLErrorCancelled.

Comment: Handling interactions like this is so much easier using ReactiveX, which will handle most of your issues for you. There is a Swift version of Rx: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift   Also, take a look at this 3-part tutorial on how to use RxSwift (which even covers examples close to your use case): http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/ios/rxswift-by-examples-1-the-basics/

Comment: @tx2.. Cancelling the request will cancel only the urlrequest which is establishing the connection. After getting the response, calling request.cancel wont cancel the completion block's activity.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't understand the full question, but now I think I got it. So I guess the solution should be something like a flag that tells you what is the last button that is pressed and inside each closure only execute the task if the flag indicates that the type is the same of the respective button.